# Is there a way to pause ddclient?

Tags: dynamic-ip, ddclient, opendns

I use ddclient to update my OpenDNS account for my home network (the router doesn't have this capability). Recently, I've been traveling and, at times, when my laptop joins another network it automatically updates that network's ip to my account (too bad for them, they're now having web filtering) and my home network loses it's OpenDNS filters.

**So, is there a way to pause ddclient updates easily?**

Comment: See also: [Restrict ddclient updates to home network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049918/restrict-ddclient-updates-to-home-network)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround:

**To pause:**

```
sudo chmod -x /usr/sbin/ddclient
```

**To reenable:**

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/ddclient
```